# How to check if checkbox is checked and if file uploaded has specific filename

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have the code below. This is a form that enables the user to upload files. I have included checkboxes that the user should tick if the file they are uploading corresponds to one listed. I then want to check if the file being uploaded has a filename that corresponds to  the checkbox selected from the list:

```
<!--SCRIPT 2 ensures that text fields are not left blank on Project form-->
    <!--SCRIPT 2 START-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateproject()
        {
            valid = true;
            if (document.input.bhu_no.value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please enter a BHU #")
                valid = false;
                }
            else if (document.input.projectname.value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please enter a Project Name")
                valid = false;
                }       
            else if (document.input.projectlead.value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please enter a the Project Lead Name")
                valid = false;
                }   
            else if (document.input.projectgoal.value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please enter a Project Goal Description")
                valid = false;
                }   
            else if (document.input.projectstartdate.value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please enter a Project Start Date")
                valid = false;
                }   
            else if (document.input.projectenddate.value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please enter a Project End Date")
                valid = false;
                }
            /*else if (document.input.brd.value == "BRD")
                {
                alert ("Please upload a BRD with BRD in the title")
                valid = false;
                }   */
            else if(document.getElementById("uploaded").value == "")
                {
                alert ("Please attach a file to be uploaded")
                valid = false;
                }                       
            return valid;
        }   
    </script>
    <!--SCRIPT 2 END-->
    <head>
<body id="wrapper">
    <script type='text/JavaScript' src='calendarwidget.js'></script>
<!--////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                    PROJECT FORM START
    \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
-->         
            <center><a href="#" class="show_hide"><input style="font-size:16px;" type="button" value="Rules for Uploading Files" /></a></center>
            <div class="slidingDiv">
                <ul>
                    <li type="1">
                        Creation of folders manually without filling out upload forms should not be done
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        File names should be descriptive and give information about what is contained within the file
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        Files uploaded must be in either Read or Read/Write property otherwise others will not be able to view the files
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        Fill out text fields on upload forms fully and to the best of your knowledge
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        Try and have the most recent document on the server at all times. If you want to keep many versions of a document on the server the 
                        file name must end with underscore ‘_’ , capital ‘V’ and the version number (e.g. ‘KB How-to_V4.key’).
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        At the end of a project upload all files related to the project onto the Knowledge Base
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        Documents uploaded to the server can not be edited, if you wish to edit a document contact the uploader of the document
                    </li>
                    <br />
                    <li type="1">
                        When you have completed mass uploading files to the server ensure you ‘Eject’ the server
                    </li> 
                </ul>
            </div>




            <div id="selectproject">    
            <br />
            <br />      
                <form name="input" action="uploadproject.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return validateproject();">
                    <table class="bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                BHU #
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input class="uploadform" type="text" name="bhu_no" maxlength="4" size="4"/>
                                <a style='font-size:12px;' href="https://biweb3.corp.apple.com/compliance/index.php/concept/search" target="_blank"><i>Search for BHU #</i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Project Name
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input class="uploadform" size="50" type="text" name="projectname" onkeyup="valid(this)" onblur="valid(this)" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Project Lead
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input class="uploadform" size="18" type="text" name="projectlead"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Project Wiki
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input class="uploadform" size="50" type="text" name="projectwiki"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                BPR Track
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="bprtrack">
                                    <option value="">
                                        --BLANK--
                                    </option>   
                                    <option value="Manufacturing">
                                        Manufacturing
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="Logistics">
                                        Logistics
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="Supply Chain">
                                        Supply Chain
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="AOS">
                                        AOS                                     
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="Supply/Demand Management">
                                        Supply/Demand Management                                        
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="Procurement">
                                        Procurement                                     
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="BI">
                                        BI                                      
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="Emerging Markets">
                                        Emerging Markets
                                    </option>                                   
                                </select>
                            </td>   
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Project Goal
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="uploadform" rows="7" cols="50" name="projectgoal"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>   
                        <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Date Start
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <INPUT TYPE='text' class="uploadform" id="projectstartdate" name="projectstartdate" SIZE='12' maxlength="10" />
                                <img src='Images/scw.gif' title='Click Here' alt='Click Here' onclick="scwShow(scwID('projectstartdate'),event);" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Date End
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="uploadform" id="projectenddate" name="projectenddate" SIZE='12' maxlength="10" />
                                <img src='Images/scw.gif' title='Click Here' alt='Click Here' onclick="scwShow(scwID('projectenddate'),event);" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Process(es) Effected<br />
                                <i style='font-size:12px;'>(User Inputted, not required)</i>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                            <div class='container'>
                                <?php

                                    $Results = mysql_query("SELECT processname FROM Knowledge.Process");

                                    while($Loadingrow = mysql_fetch_array($Results)) 
                                    {               
                                    echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$Loadingrow[processname]*' name='processname[]'>";
                                    echo $Loadingrow['processname'];
                                    echo "<br />";
                                    };
                                ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Files Uploaded</th>
                            <td>
                                <input class="uploadform" type="checkbox" name="brd" value="BRD"/>BRD<br />
                                <input class="uploadform" type="checkbox" name="playback" value="playback"/>Playback Doc.<br />
                                <input class="uploadform" type="checkbox" name="function" value="function"/>Functional Spec.<br />
                                <input class="uploadform" type="checkbox" name="work" value="work"/>Work Instruction<br />
                                <input class="uploadform" type="checkbox" name="processf" value="processf"/>Process Flow<br />
                            </td>
                            </tr>                           
                            <tr>    
                            <th>
                                Upload File
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="file" name="uploaded" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
                <br />  
                <input style='font-size:2em;' type="submit" value="Upload All" name="upload"/>
        </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

I want to know how to check if the checkbox 'brd' is checked and if the file that is being uploaded has a specific name. If the filename is correct the upload should complete, if not an error message should be thrown.
I'm not sure how to check the checkbox before the page has posted and also I don't know how to check the filename of the file being uploaded...
Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To check a checkbox is checked in Javascript, u need to do like this.

```
if(document.input.projectstatus.checked == true) {

    // CODE GOES HERE

}
```

Assume `projectstatus` is a checkbox name.

Then to check whether an uploaded file has a specific name, try this.

```
<?php

   if($_FILES["file"]["name"] == "specificname") {

            // CODE GOES HERE

   }

?>
```

Assume `file` is a field name in form.

Comment: Thanks for this!The checking a checkbox works correctly but the code to check the filename doesn't work at all...Would the code provided work in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

In your JS you have written

```
document.getElementById("uploaded")
```

whereas in your HTML you have

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded" />
```

please add **ID="uploaded"**

Comment: Hi, I've added this if statement in and added in the id to the html but it still doesn't work:else if (document.input.brd.checked == true && document.getElementById("uploadedtest").value == "test")
     {
     alert ("Please upload a BRD with BRD in the title")
     valid = false;
     }